# 3d object - Mirror in threeJS

Tags: reflection, mirror

I am working on 3d product demo, where i need to show the product reflection/ mirror. I have tried the example - http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_m. i made a replica of the example before actually implementing it with my project. When publish it to web, nothing is displayed on the screen and in the inspect you can see the error message "TypeError: this.renderTarget.texture is undefined" in mirror.js. 
How to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Can you host your problem statement. You follow same arguments supporting into Mirror.js ( width and height and renderer ) ..?

Comment: After going through the code i figured out the below line because of which the error occurs

// MIRROR planes

 groundMirror = new THREE.FlatMirror( renderer, camera, { clipBias: 0.003, textureWidth: WIDTH, textureHeight: HEIGHT, color: 0x777777 } );
    mirrorMesh.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
    scene.add( mirrorMesh );" . Thanks